# hibernate Table name pattern can not be NULL or empty

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

Unable to reverse engineer from db to java code using hibernate in eclipse env.

After creating the hibernate console config, I see the error : 
Could not get list of tables from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem. 
with stack trace of 
Table name pattern can not be NULL or empty.

I am not sure where this table name pattern should be given.

**env**

- eclipse neon
- hibernate tools 5.1.1
- mysql connector 6.0.4
- jdk 1.8

config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

full stack trace

> org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.spi.HibernateException: Could not
>   get list of tables from database. Probably a JDBC driver problem. 
>   Configured schema:null Configured catalog:null Available schemas:
>   Available catalogs:   information_schema   mysql   performance_schema 
>   test
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:139)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:108)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:231)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) Caused
>   by: java.sql.SQLException: Table name pattern can not be NULL or
>   empty.    at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:569)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:537)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:527)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:512)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:480)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getTables(DatabaseMetaData.java:3844)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.JDBCMetaDataDialect.getTables(JDBCMetaDataDialect.java:27)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.TableProcessor.processTables(TableProcessor.java:39)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:58)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractJDBCReaderFacade.readDatabaseSchema(AbstractJDBCReaderFacade.java:52)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:134)
>     ... 7 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not configured default schema so hibernate doesn't know where it should get tables. You can do it like this:

`<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?currentSchema=shema_name</property>`

Also watch probable answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083230/mybatis-generator-column-name-pattern-can-not-be-null-or-empty)

Comment: I tried passing currentSchema=test

getting the same error.

Comment: @JeyaBalaji did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083230/mybatis-generator-column-name-pattern-can-not-be-null-or-empty)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Maksym.  nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true did the trick.